# Magento: Failed to load resource - Quando idioma esta definido para pt_BR

Tags: magento

Após seguir o passo a passo para instalação do Magento, ao tentar acessar tanto o frontend quando o painel administrativo, o site não carrega os arquivos de css, javascript e imagens.

Após alguma pesquisa descobri que precisava rodar um comando para gerar os arquivos estáticos.

```
cd /var/www/html/magento
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Após executar a ferramenta:

```
#:/var/www/html/magento$ sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Requested languages: en_US
Requested areas: frontend, adminhtml
Requested themes: Magento/blank, Magento/luma, Magento/backend
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> en_US ===
=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> en_US ===
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> en_US ===
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2136 files; errors: 0
---

........................................................
Successful: 2061 files; errors: 0
---

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2012 files; errors: 0
---

=== Minify templates ===

Successful: 869 files modified
---

New version of deployed files: 1494363632
```

Mas mesmo após isso, continua ocorrendo o erro

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) /magento/pub/static/version1494362497/frontend/Magento/luma/pt_BR/css/print.css
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O magento, no momento da instalação, foi configurado para o idioma `pt_BR`.

E o comando da forma como foi executado 'sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy' gera os arquivos para o idioma default (en_US)

Para resolver o problema é preciso passar um parâmetro extra que indica para qual idioma devem ser gerados os arquivos estáticos.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_BR
```

Com isso a falha deixa de ocorrer

```
Requested languages: pt_BR
Requested areas: frontend, adminhtml
Requested themes: Magento/blank, Magento/luma, Magento/backend
=== frontend -> Magento/blank -> pt_BR ===
=== frontend -> Magento/luma -> pt_BR ===
=== adminhtml -> Magento/backend -> pt_BR ===
..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2012 files; errors: 0
---

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2061 files; errors: 0
---

.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Successful: 2136 files; errors: 0
---

=== Minify templates ===

Successful: 869 files modified
---

New version of deployed files: 1494363897
```